# Sending a message from a server to android when user is viewing a WebView

Tags: android, webview

Suppose, using the following code the user goes to a payment gateway.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/payment-test/gateway-12234");

    }
 }
```

When the user buys, the payment gateway website send for me `trans_id` and `id_get` variables. Now I check the variables and and if they were correct, I should a message such as `Received` to the user. but the problem is, the user is viewing the `Webview`.

Scenario of a request is this means, first the user should request to a `php` file and the `php` file responds. But I want the user goes to the payment gateway website and then if the payment was made, now the `php` file responds to the user.

The problem is the user is viewing the `WebView`. How can I do the `WebViewActivity` class get the message from `php` file? The problem is that the `WebViewActivity` class first requests to a payment gateway website and not to the `php` file and as the result the `php` file can not get a request from `WebViewActivity` class directly and without a request, how can it react to the `WebViewActivity` class and the `WebViewActivity` class can get the response??

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to this is not very solid. For one, you should probabaly have an API based system, build the UI natively and use the api for calls.

I do not believe you can respond to php events, but you can with JS. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Again, your issue is more your overall approach. I would reevaluate the way your coming at it.